# Keyboard shortcut to switching tabs in Sametime 7.5.1 and Lotus Notes 8.0

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lotus-notes, lotus-sametime

Any idea how to do this? The regular old Ctrl+Tab doesn't work on these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried SameTime 8.0 and 8.0.2, and Ctrl+Tab works to go between IM tabs (either vertical or horizontal).

For Notes, you can press Ctrl+F8.  Look in the help under the topic "Working with window tabs", or "Switch window tabs"

You can also press Alt+W to get the window menu, then select the number of the desired window.

There are probably another dozen ways to do it... 
Like Ctrl+Shift+T, which brings up the thumbnails view of the tabs.

Use the Help, and Search for Keyboard Shortcuts for complete lists.

Comment: Any idea how to change these mappings?

Comment: Isn't http://www.autohotkey.com/ the answer to all keyboard remaps...

Comment: Thanks for the Ctrl+Tab shortcut in Sametime. I used to press Ctrl+F and search again the name of the user I was chatting with and that was rather time consuming.